# Is there a better lysis buffer than this for fungal DNA extraction?

Tags: molecular-biology, experimental

I've being using this lysis buffer for fungal DNA extraction,lysis buffer - 400mM TRis-HCl(pH8.0), 60mM EDTA(pH8.0), 150mM NaCl, 1% SDS and containing 40microgram/ml RnaseA.

It is keep giving very light bands on 1% agarose gel and shear appearence. After extraction I have to follow PCR and sequencing. If there are inhibitors, how can I get rid of those ?

Comment: Do you Fungi contain pigment, especially melanin? This is a potent inhibitor for PCR. If not, you could start by trying a phenol/chloroform extraction.

Comment: yeah they have pigments,one sample was a penicillium,  i did PCR for these DNA extractions (didn't make any changes to the lysis buffer) but I got good bands after PCR,my primers were ITS1 and ITS4. But I didn't get PCR results for extractions I did more than 4 days ago. thank you for the answer.